# laravel if form value equals database value

Tags: php, laravel

I want check if my form value equals in database value in laravel

Here is my controller class

```
    public function code_post(Request $request, $id)
{
    $sms_token_in = $request->sms_token_in;
    $sms_token=Auth::user()->sms_token;

    DB::table('users')->where('id',$id , 'sms_token_in' ,$sms_token)->update([

        'sms_verify'=>'1'

    ]);

    return redirect('/panel')->with('edit','pending');
}
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update to

> DB::table('users')->where(['id',$id ])->where([ 'sms_token_in'
>   ,$sms_token])->update(['sms_verify'=>'1' ]);

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\GatewayController::code_post(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Show your route file.@SinaMaafi

Comment: Route::get('/panel/code', 'GatewayController@code');
Route::post('/panel/code', 'GatewayController@code_post');

Comment: update to Route::post('/panel/code/{id}', 'GatewayController@code_post');

Comment: thank you problem fixed but when i submit the form sms_verify still 0 and don't change to 1

Comment: `DB::table('users')->where(['id',$id ])->where([ 'sms_token_in' ,$sms_token])->update(['sms_verify'=>1  ]) ` try this, and check the data type in your database

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to use where is 
two parameters, 1: database field name, 2: value
three parameters (field name, operator, value) ('1', '>=', 3)

```
DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->where('sms_token_in', $sms_token)->update([
   'sms_verify'=>'1'
]);
```

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\GatewayController::code_post(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DB::table('users')->where([
 ['id',$id],
 ['sms_token_in', $sms_token]
])->update([
   'sms_verify'=>'1'
]);
```

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\GatewayController::code_post(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: share your blade form to check the post url

Answer (score 0):

First you must accept two parameter from your function. Look like only you are passing only one.

change function parameter to

```
public function code_post(Request $request, $id = 0)
```

then

```
if(!empty($id)){
    User::where(['id' => $id,'sms_token_in' => $sms_token])->update([
        'sms_verify'=>'1'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// you can do this in two way

```
 public function code_post(Request $request, $id)
{
$sms_token_in = $request->sms_token_in;
$sms_token=Auth::user()->sms_token;

DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->where('sms_token_in' ,$sms_token)->update([

    'sms_verify'=>'1'

]);

return redirect('/panel')->with('edit','pending');
}
```

//2nd way

```
    public function code_post(Request $request, $id)
    {
    $sms_token_in = $request->sms_token_in;
    $sms_token=Auth::user()->sms_token;

    DB::table('users')->where(['id',$id , 'sms_token_in' ,$sms_token])->update([

      'sms_verify'=>'1'

    ]);

    return redirect('/panel')->with('edit','pending');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best whey to do it is on Validators in laravel so, if it don't exist create a classe validator that extends "LaravelValidator" and do it:

```
protected $rules = [
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
            'sms_token_in' => 'required|unique:your_table_name',
        ],
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [],
    ]; protected $messages = [
        'sms_token_in.unique' => 'Your duplicate message!'
    ];
```

In your controller instantiate your validator in construct like it:

```
public function __construct(MyValidatorClass $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }
```

And in your controller function store do it, before your persist on database.

```
$this->validator->with($data)->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE);
```

In this way, you can use validator from Laravel to check and return anything you want to your user.

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(Request $request){


   //validate
   $request->validate([
    'email'=>'required|email',
    'user_pass'=>'required|min:5|max:12'
   ]);

   $userInfo=Employee::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
   if(!$userInfo){
    return back()->with('fail','We do not recognize your email address');
   }else{
    //check password

        if($request->user_pass=$userInfo->user_pass){
        $request->session()->put('LoggedUser', $userInfo->emp_id);
        return redirect('/employee/dashboard');
    }else{
        return back()->with('fail','Incorrect password');
    }
   }
}
```

In this method im check if the user_pass from request is equal to $userInfo->user_pass that query from database.

if($request->user_pass=$userInfo->user_pass)